# Webscraping- how to append columns

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup, append

I am scraping multiple google scholar pages and I have already written code using beautiful soup to extract information of title, author, journal.

This is a sample page.
https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ&hl=en

I want to now extract information on h-index,i-10 index and citations. When I inspected the page, I saw that all these have the same class names (gsc_rsb_std). Given this, my doubt is

1. How to extract this information using beautiful soup? The following code extracted information on citations. How to do it for the other two since the class name is the same?

```
columns['Citations'] = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'gsc_rsb_std'}).text
```

2. There is only one value for name, citations, h-index and i-index. However, there are multiple rows of papers. Ideally, I want my output in the following form.

```
Name  h-index  paper1
Name  h-index  paper2
Name  h-index  paper3
```

I tried the following and I am getting the output as above but only the last paper is repeated. Not sure what is happening here.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
columns = {}
columns['Name'] = soup.find('div', {'id': 'gsc_prf_in'}).text
           
papers = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'gsc_a_tr'})

for paper in papers:        
   columns['title'] = paper.find('a', {'class': 'gsc_a_at'}).text
   File.append(columns)
```

My output is like this. Looks like there is something wrong with the loop.

```
Name h-index paper3
Name h-index paper3
Name h-index paper3
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the syntax error, you can either enclose the xpath string in single quotes, or use single quotes inside the string.  `columns['Name'] = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gsc_prf_in"]')`

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using :has and :contains and target by search string

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

searches = ['Citations', 'h-index', 'i10-index']
r = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ&hl=en')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for search in searches:
    all_value = soup.select_one(f'td:has(a:contains("{search}")) + td')
    print(f'{search} All:', all_value.text)
    since_2016 = all_value.find_next('td')
    print(f'{search} since 2016:', since_2016.text)
```

You could also have used pandas `read_html` to grab that table by index.

---

Selenium question:

The element has an id, which is faster to match on using css selectors/find_element_by_id e.g.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("gsc_prf_in").text
```

I see no need, however, for selenium when scraping this page.

Comment: Thanks! I used selenium because the page is dynamic. Also, beautiful soup is limited in functionality in cases such as these where there are elements with same tag/attribute name. I can now extract the information using selenium. But, the third issue still remains.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with either of those statements. The above code extracts exactly what you requested without the need for selenium. Did you try running it?

Comment: the above code does work. But, I just copy pasted. As a beginner, I wouldn't know how to do this myself. driver.find_element_by_xpath is a lot easier.

Comment: You asked how to do this with beautifulsoup -  I showed you one way. You asked about the selenium method and I answered, indirectly, that xpath is an inefficient route and gave a better method. I do understand the point about using methods that you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SelectorGadgets](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab CSS selectors.

Element(s) highlighted in:

- **red** excludes from search.
- **green** included in the search.
- **yellow** is guessing what the user is looking to find and needs additional clarification.

Grab h-index:

[image]

Grab i10-index:

[image]

---

[Code and example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-pythonserpapi#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
}
  
html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ&hl=en', headers=headers, proxies=proxies).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for cited_by_public_access in soup.select('.gsc_rsb'):
  citations_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  citations_since2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(1) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  h_index_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  h_index_2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr:nth-child(2) .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  i10_index_all = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_sc1+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  i10_index_2016 = cited_by_public_access.select_one('tr~ tr+ tr .gsc_rsb_std+ .gsc_rsb_std').text
  articles_num = cited_by_public_access.select_one('.gsc_rsb_m_a:nth-child(1) span').text.split(' ')[0]
  articles_link = cited_by_public_access.select_one('#gsc_lwp_mndt_lnk')['href']
  
  print('Citiation info:')
  print(f'{citations_all}\n{citations_since2016}\n{h_index_all}\n{h_index_2016}\n{i10_index_all}\n{i10_index_2016}\n{articles_num}\nhttps://scholar.google.com{articles_link}\n')
```

Output:

```
Citiation info:
55399
34899
69
59
148
101
23
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=list_mandates&hl=en&user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Scholar Author API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference, in a particular example, is that you don't have to guess and tinker with how to grab certain elements of the HTML page.

Another thing is that you don't have to think about how to solve the CAPTCHA, (it could appear at some point) or find good proxies if there's a need for many requests.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "author_id": "cp-8uaAAAAAJ",
  "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

citations_all = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['all']
citations_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][0]['citations']['since_2016']
h_inedx_all = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['all']
h_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][1]['h_index']['since_2016']
i10_index_all = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['all']
i10_index_2016 = results['cited_by']['table'][2]['i10_index']['since_2016']

print(f'{citations_all}\n{citations_2016}\n{h_inedx_all}\n{h_index_2016}\n{i10_index_all}\n{i10_index_2016}\n')

public_access_link = results['public_access']['link']
public_access_available_articles = results['public_access']['available']

print(f'{public_access_link}\n{public_access_available_articles}')
```

Output:

```
55399
34899
69
59
148
101

https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=list_mandates&hl=en&user=cp-8uaAAAAAJ
23
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.